# Showing hidden table after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form where I am selecting project name and entering sheet name.
After clicking submit button it shows the last inserted record in a table format but after clicking submit it shows the table but as soon as the reloading the page gets over it hides the table. and clicking the submit button it shows the table. How can I solve this issue?

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="button" class="btn-success btn">Submit</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
      $("#table").show();
    });
  });
</script>

<?php 
  include('controller.php');
  $s4 = "SELECT * FROM col_heading ORDER BY coln_id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $res = mysqli_query($bd, $s4);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>  

<table class="table table-bordered" id="table" style="width:50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.no</th>
      <th>Column Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td id="h1:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php  echo $row['h1']; ?>
      </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td id="h2:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo $row['h2']; ?>
      </td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>3</td>
      <td id="h3:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo $row['h3']; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: change button type="button" to avoid reloading the page

Comment: but on submit it submits data to database I cant do that

Comment: make use of ajax to submit the form and show the table after submit is successful

Comment: 2 options. Submit via ajax (and stop the default browser post), or hide/show the table via php

Comment: Your problem is some how not clear. You mean the table should remain visible after reload?
If yes is there any other JS function which is hiding it on ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  `e.preventDefault();` inside your submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#table").show();
  });
});
```

If you want to do something on submit then its better to use ajax call inside the click function and get it done.

Put your php in a new file

**update.php**

```
<?php 
  include('controller.php');
  $s4 = "SELECT * FROM col_heading ORDER BY coln_id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $res = mysqli_query($bd, $s4);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
```

Make an ajax call to update.php from inside click function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#table").show();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'update.php',
           data: '<pass any data here>',
           success: function(response){
             // do something with the resposne
           }
        });
      });
    });
```

**Full Code**

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="button" class="btn-success btn">Submit</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#table").show();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'update.php',
           data: '<pass any data here>',
           success: function(response){
             // do something with the resposne
           }
        });
      });
    });
</script>


<table class="table table-bordered" id="table" style="width:50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.no</th>
      <th>Column Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td id="h1:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php  echo $row['h1']; ?>
      </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td id="h2:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo $row['h2']; ?>
      </td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>3</td>
      <td id="h3:<?php echo $row['coln_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo $row['h3']; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Since there is no hint of ajax in the question, all this is likely to achieve is to stop the form doing anything

Comment: my table is got hidden after using e.preventDefault();

Comment: make sure you have parameter e to click  function `function(e)`

Comment: I have 2js + 1ajax functions 1st I am using for depenednt select box. Second to show hidden table and third to edit the table I have given above.

Comment: @Nadir Laskar is it on onclick event? <button type="submit" name="submit" id="button" class="btn-success btn" onClick="e.preventDefault();">Submit</button>

Comment: it was showing e is not defined. But I am trying updated code it may help me.